# What is the definition of Building integrated photovoltaics?

Tags: photovoltaics

What is the definition of BIPV?
Building integrated photovoltaics emerged as a new way of reducing energy consumption. However, the question is how do these systems work?

Answer (score 0):

"Building Integrated" can mean that the pv panels are the waterproofing roof layer in place of the roof tiles.

That is compared to pv panels mounted on the roof supported some small distance (10cm) above the existing roof tiles.

The pv panels work the same in either case as long as the roof integrated panels have sufficient cooling so that the performance is not degraded with the temperature (pv panels suffer from reduced output as their temperature increases).

Answer (score 0):

Photovoltaics are build-integrated when they are part of the fabric of the building envelope itself, rather than modules which are mounted onto the external envelope.

BIPV can be [roof tiles](https://www.tesla.com/en_GB/solarroof), [windows](https://www.pilkington.com/en/global/products/product-categories/solar-energy/pilkington-sunplus-bipv) or [curtain-wall](http://en.hanergythinfilmpower.com/index.php?m=content&c=index&a=lists&catid=77).

While they come in and out of fashion, they have been completely eclipsed by the growth in rooftop PV and utility-scale standalone PV, which now completely dominate the market, leaving BIPV as a small niche market. While it is conceivable that this could become a signicant growth market, it is more likely to remain little more than a rounding error in global PV figures.

Comment: In some places, integrating pv into the roof gives a higher grant from the authorities :) guess how I know...

Answer (score 0):

BIPV works by converting light energy into electrical energy. The voltage output is usually connected to batteries and possibly by inverter to the national grid. Heat is an enemy of energy conversion in PV cells which means surface cooling is important.

Wind turbines similarly use voltage  inversion to convert energy to national grid power.

Answer (score -1):

One of the most recent energy consumption methods is using PV panels in front of the buildings. In abbreviation, the system calls BIPV (Building Integrated PhotoVoltaic). The generated electricity in this type of system strongly depends on the outdoor conditions which could affect the temperature of the panel and consequently increase the efficiency.